# C# mongo GridFS: query over file metadata property?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, gridfs

In my .net core 3.1 application, I'm using MongoDriver GridFS for storing files in the mongo db.
I'm also providing custom metadata to be stored together with a mongo `files` object.

```
    _gridFSBucket.UploadFromBytesAsync(fileName,
            fileByteArray,
            new GridFSUploadOptions
            {
                Metadata = new FileMetadata
                {
                    Version = 1,
                    AntragId = 313213,
                    DocumentType = "photo"
                }
                .ToBsonDocument()
            });
```

Which results:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9080ad80e2b65e90e2ba35"),
"length" : NumberLong(263356),
"chunkSize" : 261120,
"uploadDate" : ISODate("2020-04-10T14:20:30.457Z"),
"md5" : "af3e6e52680662f5a33c69d2ee16f5c5",
"filename" : "3tfa5mju.5cl",
"metadata" : {
    "Version" : 1,
    "AntragId" : 313213,
    "DocumentType" : "photo"
    }
}
```

So far so good. But now I need to query this file by the property of the `FileMetada`
Something like (this doesn't work)

```
 var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Eq<string>(info => info.Metadata.AntragId, 1);
 var fileInfos = await _gridFSBucket.FindAsync(filter);
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Since `gridFSBucket.FindAsync(filter)` method is async, it should be awaited.

Comment: @Eldar, that's just a sample but thanks anyway. I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve values from the Metadata your need to do something like this:

`var filter = Builders<GridFSFile>.Filter.Eq("metadata.AntragId", 1);`